# Oracle_ Establishing a Mapping Between original Bind Names and Captured Binds

Tags: oracle

I need to retrieve the parameter names used in database objects so that I can save this data for future object changes and utilize them for testing.

The package Body Example:

```
create or replace package body          test_pkg

is


  procedure get_bills
  (
      o_cv       out ref_cur,
      p_comp_id       in  number,
      p_plant_id      in  number,
      p_surcharges   in number,
      p_sprach     in number
  )
  is
   
   
  begin

    open o_cv for
      select /*+ <pn>test_db.test_pkg.get_bills</pn> */
       a.company_id, a.name company_name,
       b.plant_id, b.name,
       c.invoice_number,c.billing_id,c.billing_month,c.amount,c.surcharges
       ,decode(p_sprach, 1, 2)
from company a,plant b, billing c
where a.company_id=b.company_id
and  a.company_id=c.company_id
and b.plant_id=c.plant_id
and a.company_id = p_comp_id
and b.plant_id = p_plant_id
and c.surcharges = nvl(p_surcharges, c.surcharges)
and p_plant_id is not null
;



  end;


end;
```

When I executed the package, I provided the following parameters:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQbYy.png)

I conducted a search and discovered that the values of the executed bind variables were stored in 'v$sql_bind_capture':

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoMPp.png)

To ascertain the parameter names, I have two options: either from 'all_arguments' or 'all_identifiers'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOwjo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aEto.png)

So, here I encounter two primary issues. First, I've attempted various methods to establish a relation between 'v$sql_bind_capture' and 'all_arguments' or 'all_identifiers' (for example, using position, usage_id, or line).

The second issue is: Is there a method to display the value of a bind variable when it appears in the SQL query but not in the WHERE clause? In my scenario, it's represented as null (though its actual value is 1).

The final approach I'm considering is to extract the execution plan and retrieve the peeked bind variables (e.g., :B1, :B2, and :B3) based on their values, although this may not be the best practice. This would allow me to filter and focus on these three parameters. Subsequently, I will attempt to establish a relationship between line number and position or sequence. In this scenario, these parameters are the ones of interest. Is there a method to capture these peeked binds as database records without altering them?

Another approach could involve extracting the original SELECT statements from the package and comparing them line by line to what exists in 'v$sql'. However, this could be challenging, particularly when multiple cursors are present.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjuo2.png)

for test Data set please check the below:

```
create table company (
  company_id number(9) generated as identity,
  name varchar2(100) not null,
  constraint pk_company primary key (company_id)
);
create table plant (
  plant_id number(9) generated as identity,
  company_id number(9) not null,
  name varchar2(100) not null,
  constraint pk_plant primary key (plant_id),
  constraint fk_plant_01 foreign key (company_id) references company (company_id)
);
create table billing (
  billing_id number(9) generated as identity,
  company_id number(9) not null,
  plant_id number(9) not null,
  billing_month date not null,
  invoice_number varchar(30) not null,
  amount number(18,2) not null,
  surcharges number(18,2),
  constraint pk_billing primary key (billing_id),
  constraint fk_billing_01 foreign key (company_id) references company (company_id),
  constraint fk_billing_02 foreign key (plant_id) references plant (plant_id)
);
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Generate data
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Delete all data
truncate table billing;
truncate table plant;
truncate table company;
whenever sqlerror exit rollback;
-- Generate Companies  (here 3)
insert into company (name) 
  select
    'company '||company_seq.company_number as name
  from (select rownum as company_number from dual connect by level<=500) company_seq
;
 
commit;
-- Insert attachments per company. The first company will receive three plants, the next six plants, ...
insert into plant (company_id, name) 
  select 
    company.company_id,
    'plant '||company.company_number||'.'||plant_seq.plant_number
  from (
    -- Determine the serial number for each company and the desired number of plants
    select 
      company_id, 
      dense_rank() over (order by company_id) as company_number,
      dense_rank() over (order by company_id) * 3 as amount_plants
    from company
  ) company
  join (
    -- A sequence of attachments by which to join the required rows per company with N attachments
    select rownum as plant_number from dual connect by level<=1000
  ) plant_seq on (plant_seq.plant_number <= company.amount_plants)
  -- order by 1,2
;
 
commit;
-- Generate an invoice per calendar month for each company and plant.
-- The invoice number is a random string with three letters and six digits.
-- The amount is a random value in the range 100-900 euros.
-- The surcharge of 50 euros is applied to approx. 10% of the invoices.
insert into billing (company_id,plant_id,billing_month,invoice_number,amount,surcharges)
  select 
    company.company_id,
    plant.plant_id,
    to_date('01.'||month||'.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as billing_month,
    dbms_random.string('U',3) || round(dbms_random.value(10000,99999), 0) as invoice_number,
    round(dbms_random.value(100,1000),2) as amount,
    case when dbms_random.value<0.10 then 50 else null end as surcharges
  from company
  join plant on plant.company_id = company.company_id
  join (select rownum as month from dual connect by level<=12) month_seq on (1=1)
  -- order by 1,2,3
;
```

Described in Problem-Details

Comment: Please describe your final goal: what are you going to do with this information? I'm asking because there may be much clear way to achieve the same, so to exclude XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot rely on `v$sql_bind_capture` for programmatic use like this. It does not capture every bind for every execution of every cursor. Rather, it captures a sample (at most one per child cursor). It's useful for debugging issues, particularly around datatype mismatches (and hence performance issues or conversion errors) or cursor sharing problems (why a new child cursor was created), or to get some sample values to plug into a cursor with binds taken by a DBA from the shared pool to test with, but that's about it. You can't use it to get a full set of binds used by all executions. And, it doesn't last long. As soon as the cursor is purged from the shared pool the bind captures are gone too.

Also, `all_arguments`/`all_identifiers` cannot be used to align with bind captures, as they relate to the procedure/function argument lists which have no necessary correlation to binds by the calling PL/SQL block or SQL within them. A routine can be called with named parameter notation with a totally different order than the argument list. A SQL can use values from arguments in any order it wants. You might code in such a way as to enforce a 1:1 correlation, but that's not easy to enforce. I don't think you'll find a programmatic way to get this info without modifying your package and instrumenting this yourself.

I suggest that you create a log table and modify your package to insert into it all the passed-in argument values. You can timestamp the log and add other enriched info or debugging details as desired, then use it for future tests. This is a very common technique for supporting debugging by providing values for reproducing an unanticipated problem.